# VBA If Statement within For Each for Emulation

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, emulation, bluezone

I need to update several thousand X coordinates in BlueZone. I'm using VBA to enter key commands in BlueZone VT. Unfortunately, there is no "set cursor position" command, so I am limited to using "tabs" to put the cursor where it needs to go.

At the coordinate updating screen there are two possibilities: 6 or 7 tabs depending on the presence of a 0 or not on the screen.

For example: location 241054 has a 1 and needs 7 tabs, location 241051 has a 0 and needs 6 tabs to get to the X location field for me to dump in my variable.

Here is my code:

```
Sub FiXCoord_Loop()

'Must start at IMLOA screen

Dim bzhao As Object
Set bzhao = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
bzhao.Connect ""

Dim myX As Integer
Dim res_check As Integer
Dim myLoc As Variant
'Dim res_check As Variant


myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A1000")
'myResRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D3")
myX = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value
res_check = ActiveSheet.Range("D3").Value

For Each myLoc In myRange


'end loop at blank cell
    If myLoc = "" Then
        Exit For
            End If

'Query location

bzhao.SendKey "Q"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey myLoc
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<enter>"
bzhao.Wait 0.2

'Copy screen to get res#

bzhao.Wait 1
bzhao.Copy 32
bzhao.Wait 1

'Paste info to sheet for res_check

Range("J1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


bzhao.SendKey "M"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"



'if value > 0 extra tab

If res_check > 0 Then

    bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"
    bzhao.Wait 1
    bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"
    bzhao.Wait 1
    bzhao.SendKey myX
    bzhao.Wait 0.2
    bzhao.SendKey "<enter>"
    bzhao.Wait 0.2
    bzhao.SendKey "E"
    bzhao.Wait 0.5

Else

bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"
bzhao.Wait 1
bzhao.SendKey myX
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<enter>"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "E"
bzhao.Wait 0.5

End If


Next myLoc


End Sub
```

As I'm limited to walking the screen by key commands, I am copying the screen and pasting it onto my sheet to check for the 0 or not. I cannot get the if - then statement to work, though.

The code just keeps running with 6 tabs which tells me that either the res_check value (which is a mid() statement to pull the value off the screen) is not being recognized, or the the variable doesn't update with the loop. If I run the res_check > 0 location first, though, it still does 6 tabs so I can eliminate that possibility.

As a further check I ran a TRUE FALSE check on the res_check value and it passed when dimmed as an integer. On the sheet, though, ISNUMBER() fails.

TLDR: If Then will not produce desired result - code keeps defaulting to the Else condition.
[image][image]

Comment: Please try a variation of  bzhao.SetCursor 6, 53    
bzhao.SendKey "qwrety@E"    
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 1

Comment: Hi Don, I've tried the SetCursor and talke d to the BlueZone helpdesk. It is not a supported command in VT.

Comment: @donPablo ^above

Comment: There's no Wait statement between the 5th and 6th tabs when res_check > 0. There is a Wait statement between the 5th and 6th tabs when res_check is not > 0. Which behaviour is correct?

Comment: @barrowc The wait times are set very generously to monitor the macro while running. It is just pausing for 1 second (or whatever setting). I believe that has no impact on the problem.

Comment: After the "ActiveSheet.Paste"  and before the  "If res_check > 0"  you need to move ActiveSheet.Cells(7, "P")  into res_check.  Otherwise the program is looking at the value from the first location.

Comment: @donpablo Tried it - the code wont run at all like that.

Comment: @donpablo what do you mean by (7,"P")?

Comment: Row 7, Column P   which is where the Reserve Position code value is shown after the screen Paste into J1.  Alternatively, it could be similar to the first time, but now P7 instead of D3 as ----------> res_check = ActiveSheet.Range("P7").Value

Comment: @donpablo Ah - the value is actually in cell D3 pulled out by a mid() formula. All of the values from the screen print are in column D.

Comment: @donpablo Column P is blank.

Comment: Right, res_check is in D3.  BUT, how does it get from the   bzhao.Copy 32 // Range("J1").Select // ActiveSheet.Paste // finally into D3??  I agree with you... that  " the variable doesn't update with the loop."  And further say is needs to be moved from P7 into res_check.  The screen has an orange highlight on P7 that shows a value of "1" for 241054.  What does that look like for 241051?

Comment: @donpablo Res_check updates on the screen no problem with each iteration. The screenshot is pasted into J1. Columns J1:J24 contain the pasted information. 

Cell D3 is mid(J8, 63,1) which returns 1 on the screenshot. The paste is a funky text + spaces mess. I have also tried running the mid() statement in the loop instead of declaring it; that doesnt work either.

Comment: @donpablo the orange is just a visual check. 241051 returns 0 into D3.

Comment: Going by what I see on the lower half of the paste above, I would think that Position/Reserve is cell D3 which should be mid(J7, 63, 1)  [whereas mid(J8, 63, 1) would give us Height/Reserve, instead of what we want as Position] .   Take a look at the prior characters  mid (J7, 1, 10)  vs.  mid (J8, 1,10)

Comment: @donpablo mid(J7, 63, 1) is the fx returning the desired Position value. The problem continues to be the Else condition runs in both cases.

Comment: Since this is VBA, put a breakpoint on the IF and examine the values and then F8 to single step the code.  Examine mid(J8, 63, 1) and examine res_check -- to bracket the problem.  If the values are not the same, then a move needs to be added before the IF.  Based on the value you see, use F8 to step the program and determine if the proper clause is being executed.  (crazy thought --> indent the code between the else and the endif )

Comment: @donpablo I did your indent and added the cell value directly to the If Then statement versus using a variable. It works! Thanks for keeping up on this one with me!

Answer (score 0):

The below code works.

Cell D3 =mid(J7, 63, 1) and cell D8 =D3*1

I also did @donpablo's suggested indent (see comments).

```
Sub FiXCoord_Loop()

'Must start at IMLOA screen

Dim bzhao As Object
Set bzhao = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
bzhao.Connect ""

Dim myX As Integer
Dim res_check As Integer
Dim myLoc As Variant



myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A1000")
myX = ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Value
res_check = ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value

For Each myLoc In myRange


'end loop at blank cell
    If myLoc = "" Then
        Exit For
            End If

'Query location

bzhao.SendKey "Q"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey myLoc
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<enter>"
bzhao.Wait 0.2

'Copy screen to get res#

bzhao.Wait 1
bzhao.Copy 32
bzhao.Wait 1

'Paste info to sheet for res_check

Range("J1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

'Modify data

bzhao.SendKey "M"
bzhao.Wait 0.2
bzhao.SendKey "<tab><tab><tab><tab><tab>" 'tab to Res


'Decide 6 or 7 tabs

If ActiveSheet.Range("D8").Value > 0 Then

    bzhao.Wait 0.1
    bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"

Else

    End If

bzhao.Wait 0.1
bzhao.SendKey "<tab>"
bzhao.Wait 0.1
bzhao.SendKey myX
bzhao.Wait 0.1
bzhao.SendKey "<enter>"
bzhao.Wait 0.1
bzhao.SendKey "E"
bzhao.Wait 0.5


Next myLoc


End Sub
```