# VBA Variables within a Loop - BlueZone Emulation

Tags: vba, loops, bluezone

When I run the below code I cannot pass "Qty" to BlueZone. It will successfully pass the for each variable "aisle" using SendKey within the loop. I tested the outputs on the active sheet and I get the values based on myRange.Offset(0,n).

I have an n x 4 array that I want to loop through. I need to pass a different set of variables for each iteration.

Is my structure wrong?

BlueZone is terminal emulation.

https://www.rocketsoftware.com/products/rocket-bluezonepassport-terminal-emulator/rocket-bluezone-terminal-emulation

```
Sub Grooming1()



Dim bzhao As Object
Set bzhao = CreateObject("BZWhll.WhllObj")
bzhao.Connect ""


Dim aisle As Variant
Dim Qty As Variant
Dim LDAP As Variant
Dim Priority As Variant

Set myRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A1000")
'Set myQty = ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B1000")
'Set myLDAP = ActiveSheet.Range("C2:C1000")
'Set myPriority = ActiveSheet.Range("D2:D1000")


For Each aisle In myRange

Set Qty = myRange.Offset(0, 1)
Set LDAP = myRange.Offset(0, 2)
Set Priority = myRange.Offset(0, 3)

'end loop at blank cell
    If aisle = "" Then
        Exit For
            End If

bzhao.SendKey "<PF3>"
bzhao.Wait 0.5
bzhao.SendKey Qty '<---ERROR
bzhao.Wait 0.5

'ActiveSheet.Range("F2") = Qty
'ActiveSheet.Range("F3") = LDAP
'ActiveSheet.Range("F4") = Priority
'ActiveSheet.Range("F5") = aisle

Next aisle


End Sub
```

Comment: I have never heard of "bluezone" and have no idea what "BZWhll.WhllObj" is. I doubt that very many people reading this question will know what that is. It might help if you provide some context including links to the relevant documentation. The fact that you are using `SendKey` is not very encouraging. That is almost impossible to reliably debug. It is an essentially opaque command. From our point of view, an unknown window is receiving unknown data and not working according to your unstated expectations.

Comment: @jpcoleman SendKey is certainly not ideal, but it is the only option I have to walk the emulator. I think my expectation is clear - my variable Qty is not passing. Thanks for reading; I added more detail concerning the object.

Comment: Is `Qty` a string? What is the error that you are receiving? What is the value of `myRange.Offset(0, 1)`? You are immersed in the particulars of your problem. Others might not know what you are trying to do. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @jpcoleman Qty is an integer, the first row of myRange.Offset(0,1) is 10.

Comment: Googling around a bit, it doesn't seem to be a very widely used product. For one thing, there is no Stack Overflow tag devoted to it. Perhaps there is technical support from the company (Rocket?) who makes it?  The link that you provided gives no details about what a `"BZWhll.WhllObj"` object is.

Comment: @jpcoleman They have resources on their site concerning macros. The “Bzwhll.Whll0bj” is how they suggest declaring the object. I have a dozen running macros using For Each loops, but they all have a single column range inputs with static variable passing. 

The difference with my current objective is I have a list of aisles that each have 3 unique variables associated with them. The above code is just a snippet with the problem.

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958879/vba-if-statement-within-for-each-for-emulation?noredirect=1#comment104294881_58958879

Comment: Likely only someone with knowledge of bluezone can answer your question. I created a bluezone tag since your question wasn't the first to ask about it. Your question is thus the inaugural question (though I might add the tag to some of the earlier questions that mentioned it. The tag wiki I created for it is just a stub. Someone more knowledgeable about it, such as yourself, should flesh it out.

Comment: @jpcoleman I would be happy to contribute, though I'm not familiar with the process you're referencing. How can I help with the tag?

Comment: I am not 100% sure that you can with your current rep. But -- on the tag link there should appear like "improve tag info". You can click on that, add a bit more (but not too much) info e.g. some link about VBA and bluezone and then submit it. It will enter an edit queue for approval. Sooner or later it will be approved (or perhaps rejected). This tag is unlikely to be heavily used, so I wouldn't spend too much time on it, but if a few sentences would help, it couldn't hurt to add them.

Comment: @jpcoleman Understood - done!

Answer (score 0):

So, my company uses BlueZone as well. We have created a function that reduces lines of code:

```
Public Function SendKey(ByVal aKey As String)
BZHost.SendKey aKey
If BZHost.WaitReady(10, 1) <> 0 Then
    Err.Raise 2049, "", "BlueZone session failed to respond within 10 second timeout limit!"
End If
```

End Function
So when you want to enter text into BlueZone:

```
SendKey Qty
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but I found it looking for BlueZone info myself.

We also use BlueZone, and our practice is to use WaitReady instead of Wait.  In fact, we double it up for some reason (but I'm new here).

The other thing I would suggest is to always use the Format function with numbers, especially if your mainframe right-justifies anything like ours.

So if you're typing into a field with a length of six digits, your code would be:

```
bzhao.SendKey "<PF3>"
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 1
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 100
bzhao.SendKey Format(Qty, "000000") ' padded with zeros
bzhao.SendKey Format(Format(Qty, "@"), "@@@@@@") ' padded with spaces
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 1
bzhao.WaitReady 10, 100
```

Finally, shouldn't your Offset be on the `aisle` object, not `myRange`?  Otherwise, `Qty` will always be the value of the first row no matter what row `aisle` is...

Best,
Kevin